# How do I set up network containers in Bluemix?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I've run two Alpine containers in Bluemix, used a link, and tried a tracert, and it's timing out. Is there something else I need to do to allow them to talk?

```
$ docker run -d --name net-a alpine sleep 99999
$ docker run -d --name net-b --link net-a:net-a alpine sleep 99999
$ docker exec -i net-b sh
traceroute net-a
traceroute to net-a (172.31.0.27), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  instance-0055703a (172.31.0.28)  2998.949 ms !H  2999.897 ms !H  2999.970 ms !H
```

Same commands work fine with my local Docker engine.

Answer (score 0):

This should just work - one noticeable difference vs local is that the containers take a bit longer to come up and have networking.  Check that the first is in state Running before starting the second, and that the second is in state Running before the exec, perhaps?

Just did a quick test using one of my images (note some delays between running the below commands), and I'm seeing connectivity:

```
# cf ic run --name net-a myimage
ba11348e-2945-4aed-9ddf-8b85ec418423

# cf ic ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE     COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
ba11348e-294        myimage   ""                  About a minute ago   Running 4 seconds ago                       net-a

# cf ic run --name net-b --link net-a:net-a myimage
a45e9783-47f6-499b-ad46-2f49b275adbc

# cf ic ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
a45e9783-47f        myimage   ""                  48 seconds ago      Running 10 seconds ago                       net-b
ba11348e-294        myimage   ""                  2 minutes ago       Running a minute ago                         net-a

# cf ic exec -ti net-b bash
root@instance-00c1f798:/# traceroute net-a
traceroute to net-a (172.31.0.22), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  net-a (172.31.0.22)  2.398 ms  2.199 ms  2.224 ms
```